# How to manage model returned from controller in .jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a controller that has the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/officeIndex", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ModelAndView showOffices() {
        List<Office> offices = officeServiceImpl.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("officeIndex", "command", offices);
    }
```

In the corresponding .jsp, I wish to show attributes of each office, and the best method I've come up with is:

```
<h1>List of Offices</h1>
    <c:forEach var="office" items="${offices.office}">
        <p>${office.officeName}</p>
    </c:forEach>
```

My console shows that I am selecting the list of offices via SQL.  The page displays only the `<h1>` portion of the code.  Can anybody help me show the list of office names here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to the following.  You must add the object to the result.  You must configure the c:foreach to use `var` as the individual object, `items` as the object you pass from controller and then `${var.itemAttribute}` to get desired display.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/officeIndex", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ModelAndView showOffices() {
        List<Office> offices = officeServiceImpl.findAll();
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("officeIndex", "command", offices);
        result.addObject("offices", offices);
        return result;
    }
```

.jsp:

```
<h1>List of Offices</h1>
    <c:forEach var="office" items="${offices}">
        <p>${office.officeName}</p>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Change `new ModelAndView("officeIndex", "command", offices)` to `new ModelAndView("officeIndex", "offices", offices)` and get rid of the `result.addObject(..)`. You were adding the `offices` object as two model attributes, one with name `command` and one with name `offices`. There's just no point.